# Toyota Corolla metal clanking sound after driving

Tags: toyota, noise, corolla, parking, metal

I noticed a metal clanking sound after driving my car not sure what’s causing it. I don’t see any leak or anything under and I can’t hear it inside the car or while driving. I began to noticed it after parking and hear it.

Please see the link for the video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4aa4.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The sounds look like water dripping on the metal.

It looks like your AC water dripping on the wrong one, it should be dripping straight to the floor / ground, not on the metal.

If you use AC while driving, please check if anything dripping like water on the ground.  If you can't find anything dripping then it must be AC water dripping on metal. This is bad because it will make your body parts or other parts rusty.